# Deleting Forwarding Rules from Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am running into "QUOTA_EXCEEDED" for forwarding rules. I was able to delete the forwarding rules for my current project. But it seems I have some forwarding rules from previouly deleted projects also. These are NOT tied to any REGION somehow. 
`gcloud compute forwarding-rules delete <<fwd-rule-1>>` alwys try to find the rule under `projects/current_project/regions/current_region/forwrading_rules/fwd_rule_1`

How can I delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are `"Global Forwarding Rules"` and can be deleted after the "Container Engine" was deleted from the `"Networking > Load Balancing > Advanced > Global Rules > Select All > Delete"`. 
 Deletetion of Container Engine was relevant in my case as the forwarding rules were getting created from fabric8-kubernetes docker container.